# Hystrix and Connection Pooling

Tags: java, apache, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x, hystrix

Please excuse this - it could well be a dumb newbie question.

We're using Hystrix as a Circuit Breaker between two services. To speed up performance we're using Connection Pooling. We're using the PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager from Apache HttpClient to handle the Connection Pool.

We're also using Hystrix's 'timeoutInMilliseconds' property to catch issues.

The 'problem' we have is that in normal operation it takes c130ms to create a new HTTPS connection, but once pooled the read time on those connections is c12ms.

So, we've had to set our 'timeoutInMilliseconds' threshold to be higher than we'd like so that Hystrix doesn't kick in whenever our Connection Pool decides to create a new connection. Our Non-Functional Requirements want the latency to the service to be nearer 12ms than 130ms.

Are we using Hystrix correctly? Are there other patterns we could follow when using Hystrix and Connection Pooling?

Many thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1):

You should configure Hystrix to timeout based on your TP99  + buffer latency. In your case, the TP99 latency is 130 ms. Add the median latency of ~20 ms, and configure the Hystrix to timeout at 150 ms.

Comment: Yes it has to be 150ms, But TP99 will still be 13ms in this case. 130ms is for initial connection pooling which still needs to be accomodated in configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust hystrix timeouts for specific commands during the execution of your service. But, you need to observe latency metrics from that command and code your non functional req. into it. 
It may help https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Metrics-and-Monitoring. Consequently, you may adapt this connection pool warmup or errors.

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb you have to remember is to keep timeouts at slightly higher and acceptable value over the normal/routine connection times. Keep the hystrix timeout to something like 150ms ( slightly over than the regular connection time of 130ms) so that it can handle regular connections at app startup and then continue to serve clients from the pool at a much higher speed.